# Dropdown list for Toloka project

Tags: dropdown, toloka

Could anybody give an advice on how to make dropdown lists appear only after performer types at least 5 characters in the answer field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem with the drop-down lists can be solved like this:
Add CustomSuggestSource by pasting the following code above the code of the task (exports.Task), i.e. to the very top of the JS block of your project:

```
var IGNORE_INPUT_LENGTH = 5;
var CustomSuggestSource = Backbone.Model.extend({
assets: [],
constructor: function(data, options) {
this.options = options;
this.assets = _.clone(data);
Backbone.Model.apply(this, options);
},
/**
* @param {string} query
* @returns {string[]}
*/
filterBy: function(query) {
if (query.length < IGNORE_INPUT_LENGTH) {
return [];
}
var queryString = query.toLowerCase();
return _.filter(this.assets, function(str) {
return str.toLowerCase().indexOf(queryString) >= 0;
});
}
});
```